# DNS record not resolving - even on the server itself? Causing AD issues

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2019

I have a Windows Server 2019 AD/DHCP/DNS/SQL server running on an ESXi host. Recently, I have been having trouble with domain trust dying to client machines, and now I am completely unable to join new devices to the domain. The issue appears to be resolving the SRV record for '_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.[domain]'.

I have been digging around for some time now, but nothing has been working. I confirmed that:

- The record exists in the DNS host
- The client PC is resolving queries from the DC
- The client PC can ping the domain, the hostname of the server, and the FQDN of the server
- DCDIAG reports no issues with DNS
- There are no issues in the DNS Event Viewer

What is most interesting, is that the DC itself can not resolve this host. I am using:

```
nslookup
set type=ANY
_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.[domain]
```

I can ping '_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.[domain]' as an A record, and it does resolve. It seems that it only will not resolve as a SRV record.

This is from a Windows 10 Pro VM I am using as a clean-slate test:
[VM PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgX2l.png)

Here is the record in the DC:
[DNS Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c8am.png)

TY in advance :)

Update: Randomly, the DC decided it could now see the SRV record. Client workstations can not

Comment: `unable to join new devices to the domain` what occurs when the domain join is attempted? Messages?

Comment: "An Active Directory Domain Controller could not be contacted..."
"The error was: "DNS name does not exist"
"The query was for the SRV record for '_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.[domain]'"
This is when trying to join a machine to the domain in the sysd,.cpl window.

Comment: LDAP is also required to logon. Are you logging on with cached credentials?

Comment: I am using a local admin account